# How do I install a github project with python

Tags: python, git, python-3.x, github

How do I install a github project with Pip.

When I try: pip install git+https://github.com/zhanghe06/python.git

```
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\H1h\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-m11re0lo-build\
```

I've freshly installed my pc and I am wanting to download a github project but I can't get it working.

Supposedly to fix this you download setuptools but when I do that I already have setuptools installed.

Also, a large percentage of these solutions tend to have "did not work for me" and I cannot workout how I got this to go last time.

In essence pip install git+abc.git
And an variation of that command will not work for me.
Pip install adc would work assuming pip has added that.

```
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\H1h\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-m11re0lo-build\
```

Does anyone have any idea on how to get around this as I have been stuck on this for ages and cannot see how to get around it.  Not using github is not really an option..

Comment: can you post the exact command you're running?

Comment: @wpercy Sure can, give me a sec

Comment: You must point pip at the archive for `master` branch, not at the git repository itself.

Comment: @spectras Can you clarify why example in question does not work?  Ignore the earlier comment as SO kept incorrectly editing links for whatever reason

Comment: @spectras I suppose there is the old fashion way which is adding git project to Anaconda folder?  Never actually done that before LOL